# How do I load lines from a file at an interval in NodeJS without loading the whole file into memory?

Tags: node.js, file-io, setinterval

I'm not very experienced in Node, but I'd like to load a file one line at a time and process it, with two special constraints:

- I don't want to load the entire file into memory (it could be huge)
- I want to process each line about a second apart. Ideally, at a random interval between 100ms and 2000ms

Or another way of looking at the problem: I want to treat a file as a test stream of data.

Everything I've found thus far seems to involve either loading the whole thing into an array at once, or loading it line by line but doing so pretty much instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, just found this. Dunno if there's a better way to do it, but it seems to be pretty straightforward using [line-by-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line):

```
var Random = require('random-js')();
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'), lr = new LineByLineReader(filename);

lr.on('line', function (line) {
    lr.pause(); // this blocks so the next line won't read right away.

    sendToStream(line);
    setTimeout(function () {
        lr.resume(); // resume after random interval
    }, Random.integer(100, 2000));
});
```